# Undefined reference to function in CMake Project

Tags: c++, cmake, compiler-errors, sdl

I'm really stuck in including compiled binaries to C/C++ MinGW projects using CMake.
I'm using CLion because it's my favorite IDE but it's projects are CMake-based.

In common I have .dll file and .h file (.dll.a is optional) and I tried a lot of variations with "target_link_library", "find_package" and etc, but compiling of projects returns "undefined reference to %function_name% or "returned 0x0135" which means library not found.

Example of CMake looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(untitled)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)
include_directories("SDL2/include")
add_subdirectory(SDL2)
add_executable(untitled main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(untitled SDL2)
```

And the result:

```
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2021.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.obj: in function `SDL_main':
F:/SoftwareProjects/untitled/main.cpp:16: undefined reference to `SDL_CreateWindow'
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2021.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: F:/SoftwareProjects/untitled/main.cpp:24: undefined reference to `SDL_GetWindowSurface'
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2021.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: F:/SoftwareProjects/untitled/main.cpp:26: undefined reference to `SDL_MapRGB'
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2021.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: F:/SoftwareProjects/untitled/main.cpp:26: undefined reference to `SDL_FillRect'
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2021.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: F:/SoftwareProjects/untitled/main.cpp:28: undefined reference to `SDL_UpdateWindowSurface'
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2021.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: F:/SoftwareProjects/untitled/main.cpp:30: undefined reference to `SDL_Delay'
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2021.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: F:/SoftwareProjects/untitled/main.cpp:32: undefined reference to `SDL_DestroyWindow'
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2021.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: F:/SoftwareProjects/untitled/main.cpp:34: undefined reference to `SDL_Quit'
```

Everything is OK with header files. The problem in linking .dll (and .dll.a) to project properly.
This is not about one library. My problem: I don't understand how to link it in right way. Please help me guys!

**UPDATE:**
Guys, help you so much for your advices, but problem not in SDL2 library only. I expected something general.
I have another example: I found nice library called SIGIL (http://www.libsigil.com/). I compiled everything on my own and put this to CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(SIGIL_INCLUDE_DIR libs/include)
set(SIGIL_LIB_DIR libs/)

include_directories(${SIGIL_INCLUDE_DIR})
link_directories(${SIGIL_LIB_DIR})

add_executable(MyApplication main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(MyApplication sigil)
```

Still getting undefined references to sigil functions, or process return with 0x0135 (library not found)

Comment: Also, where did you get the DLL file from, is this compiled by you or let's say "copied from somewhere"?

Comment: Do not post code in the *comments*. Instead, [edit] the **question post** and add the code to it. You may also find useful [ask].

Comment: @PhilMasteG I tried both: compiled by myself, and precompiled for MinGW64 and everytime I got the same result

Comment: Does it work if you compile from the terminal using `g++ 1.cpp -Ipath/to/includes -Lpath/to/libs -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2`? If it doesn't work, you probably have the wrong SDL2 binaries (x32 with an x64 compiler, or vice versa; you need to be more specific than *"precompiled for MinGW64"*; compiling yourself is not the easiest option since you have to make sure you have all the required dependencies, otherwise your binaries will be barely functional).

Comment: But building directly from the terminal does work, then try building with CMake in verbose mode (if you're running `make`, add `VERBOSE=1`; or, if you're running `cmake --build`, add `--verbose`), and show us the output.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I'm a win user, btw. I never tried to compile through console. As expected I've got "g++ not recognized as command"

Comment: It's a useful skill to have. Add `C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2021.3.3\bin\mingw\bin` to the PATH then try again.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ok, now I've got built application in root folder but it says "The code execution cannot proceed because SDL2.dll was not found"

Comment: This can be fixed by copying `SDL2.dll` to the directory where you have the .exe. This means that the problem is with the CMakeLists.txt...

Comment: I think that could be a problem with the SDL2 subdirectory, redefining the target SDL2, which in turn might not be correctly linked to the executable. Could you please remove the line `add_subdirectory(SDL2)` and then add a `target_link_directories(...)` with the correct directory of the SDL2.DLL? Just to make sure that you are indeed trying to link against the SDL2.dll and not against some project inside the SDL2 subdir. Also, are there any other (lib)SDL2.dll(.so/.a) files where the DLL resides?

Comment: Where is your .dll.a file? Well anyway it's seems to be some sort of ugly vendoring, so here is a neat solution: 1/ Properly install SDL2 outside your project 2/ Just use `find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)` and `target_link_libraries(untitled PRIVATE SDL2::SDL2)` in your CMakeLists 3/ During cmake configuration, add `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=<path/to/sdl2install>`

Comment: Guys, post updated